# Additional parameter for index page sort collection

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, action

I have a page which renders Question objects as a set of `<div>`'s. (I also use Pagination but I don't think it's of any significance for this particular problem).

I would like to give the user the opportunity to choose an order in which the items get displayed (aka the order of the underlying Question List.

I figured using a `<select>` list would be a simple way, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm mainly struggling with calling an Action from my controller from Javascript. This is what I have so far:

My HTML:

```
<select id="sort-select" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    @foreach (SortingType value in Enum.GetValues(typeof (SortingType)).Cast<SortingType>())
    {
        <option value="@((byte)value)">@(value.ToString())</option>
    }
</select>
```

(SortingType is an enum conatining 3 constants.)

My JavaScript:

```
function AddSort() {
    var select = document.getElementById('sort-select');

    select.onchange = function(event) {
        var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

        var url = encodeURI("@Url.Action("Index", new {topicId = ViewBag.TopicId, sort = 0})");
        url.replace('&amp;', '&');
        url.replace(0, selected);

        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

This of course gets called in document.ready.

The problem is that, when the JS runs, it forms all ampersands (&) to their escaped equivalent (&). Of course this is not working because parameters for Actions of a Controller are separated by pure ampersands.

I get this as a link when I try to change the selection:

```
http://localhost:41084/Question?topicId=-1&amp;sort=0
```

Anyone any idea on how I can solve this? I'm not sure how I can call actions from Javascript in a proper manner, and I also don't know if JavaScript is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution had to do `url = url.replace(...)` instead of just `url.replace(...)`!

My javascript now looks like this:

```
function AddSort() {
    var select = document.getElementById('sort-select');

    select.onchange = function(event) {
        var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

        var url = encodeURI("@Url.Action("Index", "Question", new {topicId = ViewBag.TopicId, sort = 0})");
        url = url.replace('&amp;', '&');
        url = url.replace(0, selected);

        window.location.href = url;
    }


}
```